# Copying a file, using impersonator, throw an Unauthorized Access Exception

Tags: c#, impersonation, networkcredentials

I am using [this Impersonator class](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10090/A-small-C-Class-for-impersonating-a-User) to copy files to a Directory with access rights.

```
public void CopyFile(string sourceFullFileName,string targetFullFileName)
{
    var fileInfo = new FileInfo(sourceFullFileName);

    try
    {
        using (new Impersonator("username", "domain", "pwd"))
        {
            // The following code is executed under the impersonated user.
            fileInfo.CopyTo(targetFullFileName, true);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

This code work almost perfectly.
The problem I am facing is when the sourceFullFileName is a file located in folder like ***C:\Users\username\Documents*** where the original user has access but the impersonator not.

The exception I am getting while trying to copy a file from such location is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: Access to the path 'C:\Users\username\Documents\file.txt' is denied.

Comment: Hey, that's my class, neat :-)

Comment: How about using [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) to see what actually happens on a file-level (actual user, actual file, actual permissions requested, etc.)

Comment: Wow!!! Happy to tell you face to face that you did a very good job. Thank you

Comment: When you impersonate as another user, it probably has no access to the initial user's home folder. If the file is not too large, how about reading it into memory first (like [`File.ReadAllBytes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes) into a `byte[]`) without impersonating, then doing the impersonation and then writing the `byte[]` into the destination file?

Comment: I will read about Process Monitor, I am not familiar with it. Correct, the original user does not have privilieges

Comment: "how about reading it into memory..." seems a good solution, I will try it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before impersonation, the current user has access to the source file path but not to the destination file path.

After impersonation, it is quite the opposite: the impersonated user has access to the destination file path but not to the source file path.

If the files are not too large, my idea would be the following:

```
public void CopyFile(string sourceFilePath, string destinationFilePath)
{
    var content = File.ReadAllBytes(sourceFilePath);

    using (new Impersonator("username", "domain", "pwd"))
    {
        File.WriteAllBytes(destinationFilePath, content);
    }
}
```

I.e.:

1. Read all content from the source file path into a byte array in memory.
2. Do the impersonation.
3. Write all content from the byte array in memory into the destination file path.

Methods and classes used here:

- [`File.ReadAllBytes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes) to read everything into memory.
- [`File.WriteAllBytes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes) to write everything from memory into the file.
- [`Impersonator`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10090/A-small-C-Class-for-impersonating-a-User) to temporarily change the identity of the current thread.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Uwe Keim idea, the following solution works perfectly:

```
    public void CopyFile(string sourceFullFileName,string targetFullFileName)
    {
        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(sourceFullFileName);

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var file = new FileStream(sourceFullFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                 byte[] bytes = new byte[file.Length];
                 file.Read(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
                 ms.Write(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
             }

            using (new Impersonator("username", "domain", "pwd"))
            {
                 using (var file = new FileStream(targetFullFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                 {
                       byte[] bytes = new byte[ms.Length];
                       ms.Read(bytes, 0, (int)ms.Length);
                       file.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                       ms.Close();
                 }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That looks strange. You are reading "something" twice (what is `ms`?). [This is what I had on my mind](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36743951/107625). Plus: This catch block without any meaning is useless. Simply omit it to have the same functionality and enhanced readability.

Comment: Updated the code. Sorry, I miss to show the memory stream part.